# 2DTopdown Shooter : Shotgun Shoot problem How can i using multiple raycast2D as same time

Tags: unity-game-engine

I create raycast2d script on my game for the HandGun and that works well when the near enemy on distance, taking damage to the enemy.

```
if (getShop.isPistol)
            {
                directionShoot = transform.up;
                RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, directionShoot, shootDist, mask.value);

                if (hit.collider != null)
                {
                    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point, Color.green);
                    hit.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("Damaged", damageTaken);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, directionShoot, Color.red);
                }

                GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab[0], firePoint[0].position, firePoint[0].rotation);
                Bullet bulletScript = bullet.GetComponent<Bullet>();
                bulletScript.velocity = firePoint[0].up * bulletForce * 10;
                bulletScript.player = gameObject;
                Destroy(bullet, 2f);
            }

else if (getShop.isShotgun)
            {
              the shotgun

            }
```

and for the shotgun, I recently use same as the Handgun instantiating one by one but I don't want to that so my question is can I use multiple raycast2d without raycastAll on the shotgun and how to add a spread bullet on it in topdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is "can i make multiple raycasts per frame" the answer is yes, you can.

You would do something like

```
List<RaycastHit2D> hits = new List<RaycastHit2D>();

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfBulletsInShotgunShot; i++){
    // modify your direction by some small amount here
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, directionShoot, shootDist, mask.value);
 
    if (hit.collider != null){
        hits.Add(hit); // add hits to your list
    }
}

// loop through deal with your hits here
```

Altering the direction slightly to spread your bullets out

Comment: I greatly appreciate, your help, I have question why `// loop through deal with your hits here` not execute when `hit.colider not null ?`  and for `directionshoot` how do I add random.range on it.

Comment: You could absolutely write the `deal with hits` as soon as you detected them. Have a look at [this here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/46770/rotate-a-vector3-direction.html) for help rotating a vector... you're going to want to pick a small +/- angle around an axis perpendicular to the direction shot. Give it a go but if you are having difficulty feel free to ask it as a proper question on here! Best of luck